# Output Not Printing Everything?

Tags: java, methods, printing, output, call

Trying to see what is wrong with my program. I don't know why the output is not printing all the way, since every method is the same, just with different names. It stops after a certain point near the end, but the code has more to it.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    //x^3 + x^2 + 1
    //2x^3 - 2x^2 - 2
    //3x^3 + 3x^2 + 3

    newrap1();
    newrap2();
    newrap3();
}
public static double func1(double x)
    {
        double f1;
        f1 = Math.pow(x, 3) + Math.pow(x, 2) + 1;
        return f1;
    }
public static double func2(double x)
    {
        double f2;
        f2 = 2*Math.pow(x, 3) - 2*Math.pow(x, 2) - 2;
        return f2;
    }
public static double func3(double x)
    {
        double f3;
        f3 = 3*Math.pow(x, 3) + 3*Math.pow(x, 2) + 3;
        return f3;
    }
public static double der1(double x)
    {
        double d1;
        d1 = 3*Math.pow(x, 2) + 2*x;
        return d1;
    }
public static double der2(double x)
    {
        double d2;
        d2 = 6*Math.pow(x, 2) - 4*x;
        return d2;
    }
public static double der3(double x)
    {
        double d3;
        d3 = 9*Math.pow(x, 2) + 6*x;
        return d3;
    }
public static void newrap1()
    {
        double x = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            double diff;
            diff = func1(x)/der1(x);
            if (diff == 0) return;
            x -= diff;
            System.out.println(Math.floor(x * 1e6) / 1e6);

        }
        System.out.println("The root is -1.465572 after 20 iterations.");
        System.out.println();
    }
public static void newrap2()
    {
        double x = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            double diff;
            diff = func2(x)/der2(x);
            if (diff == 0) return;
            x -= diff;
            System.out.println(Math.floor(x * 1e6) / 1e6);
        }
        System.out.println("The root is 1.465571 after 15 iterations.");
        System.out.println();
    }
public static void newrap3()
    {
        double x = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            double diff;
            diff = func3(x)/der3(x);
            if (diff == 0) return;
            x -= diff;
            System.out.println(Math.floor(x * 1e6) / 1e6);
        }
        System.out.println("The root is -1.465572 after 20 iterations.");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Where is the main method?

Comment: Have you tried running a debugger to see where it hangs up?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be, and what *is* the output? It would also help if you could turn this into a short but complete program - we should be able to copy and paste the code into a file, compile it, and run the program. You should try to reduce it to a minimal program that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It appears that you left out some of your code. Please provide a **complete** example that we can simply copy and paste to compile and run ourselves. Also, you should provide some example input and output.

Comment: That is the complete code. Basically, the output is supposed to show the root of the 3 equations using the Newton-Raphson method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `newrap3()` method the variable `diff` equals zero and thus the method returns without printing the rest of the output.

```
        diff = func3(x) / der3(x);
        if (diff == 0) {
            return;
        }
```

Perhaps instead of return you would want a `break`, like so:

```
        if (diff == 0) {
            break;
        }
```

Comment: wired guess. How you know how main method use here?

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera, the main method I assumed it were the first 3 function calls just in the beginning.

Comment: Changing return to break in the last method showed the entire output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In `newrap3()` at `i=22` the value of `x` is `-1.4655712318767682`.

Calling `func3(-1.4655712318767682)` will return `0` so `diff = func3(x)/der3(x);` will be `0` as well.

Then `if (diff == 0) return;` will exit `newrap3()` before it reaches 2 print statements at the bottom of the method.